# Animations in python using celluloid

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, celluloid

I was trying the first simple animation from [this](https://pypi.org/project/celluloid/) page. I am clearly a beginner at making animations. I paste the code below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera

fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot([i] * 10)
    camera.snap()
animation = camera.animate()
```

It gives me the following error.

```
Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely unintended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable that exists for as long as you need the Animation.
```

As far as I can see, animate() has already been assigned a name. Could anyone resolve this issue for me?

Comment: Your code works for me. If you use `plt.show()`, does it display something?

Comment: It does! Thanks so much @Corralien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this error (in fact is just a `UserWarning`), you have to display or save the animation. At the bottom of your code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from celluloid import Camera

fig = plt.figure()
camera = Camera(fig)
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot([i] * 10)
    camera.snap()
animation = camera.animate()

plt.show()
# OR
animation.save('test.mp4')
```